Cómo me aseguro de que los roles se asignen correctamente durante el proceso de inicio de sesión? - Next.js
En mi proyecto Next.js estoy desarrollando una aplicación que maneja dos tipos de usuarios, terapeutas y usuarios. Utilizo NextAuth para permitir el inicio de sesión con Google (esto solo tiene el rol de usuario), pero surge un problema interesante: cuando intento acceder con una cuenta de prueba creada, el sistema no esta tomando el rol de terapeuta y se encuentra asi const user = {id: "1", name: "usuario", email: "uss@mail.com", password: "12345", rol: "terapeuta"}, lo que debería restringir su acceso al dashboard de los usuarios. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Estoy utilizando este tutorial para el asignar y verificar roles, los únicos cambios son los siguientes:
en /api/auth/[...nexauth]/route.ts se encuentra:
const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [GoogleProvider({
        profile(profile: GoogleProfile) {
            //console.log(profile) -> Ver perfil en consola 
            return {
                ...profile,
                rol: "usuario", //profile.rol ??
                id: profile.sub,
            }
        },
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
        //id: 'credentials',
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
            email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "text" },
        },
        async authorize(credentials) { //credentials: any
            //Ejemplo para conocer si funciona
            const user = { id: "1", name: "isabel", email: "isa@mail.com", password: "12345", rol: "terapeuta" }
            if (credentials?.email === user.email && credentials?.password === user.password) {
                return user;
            } else {
                return null;


            }
        },
    })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) token.rol = user.rol
            return token
        },
        //usar el rol en componentes de cliente
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (session?.user) session.user.rol = token.rol
            return session
        }
    }
});
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

En app/middleware.ts agregue:
export default withAuth(
  // 'withAuth augments your 'request' with the user's token
  function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
    console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname);
    console.log(request.nextauth.token);
    if (
      request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboardU") &&
      request.nextauth.token?.rol !== "usuario"
    ) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/signin", request.url));
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
    },
  }
);
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/dashboard",
    "/admin",
    "/dashboard_U",
    "/dashboard_tera",
    "/signin",
    "/singup",
  ],
};

En el tutorial que segui creo el archivo next-auth-d.ts que contiene:
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from "next-auth";
import { JWT, DefaultJWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
      rol: string;
    } & DefaultSession;
  }
  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    rol: string;
  }
}
declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT extends DefaultJWT {
    rol: string;
  }
}


En /signin solo se tiene esto para el poder enviar los datos del formulario al route.ts:
const router = useRouter();
const [error, setError] = useState("");
// const session = useSession();
const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();

useEffect(() => {
  if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
    router.replace("/dashboardU"); //"/dashboard"
  }
}, [sessionStatus, router]);

const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = e.target[0].value;
  const password = e.target[1].value;

  const res = await signIn("credentials", {
    email,
    password,
    redirect: false,
  });
};


Comparando tu código con el tutorial, en callbacks de withAuth tienes !!!token cuando en el tutorial tienes !!token, no se si eso influya. Por otro lado y como solo tienes dos roles, puedes hacer que el campo de rol sea un array y verificar con includes para que te traiga regrese un valor booleano, ahora bien no estoy seguro de como haces el registro pero también tienes el caso de que un terapeuta puede ser un usuario, usando un arreglo también podría ayudarte con eso.

Podrías explicar como hacer que el rol sea un array?, el inicio de sesión nada mas los terapeutas inician sesión con correo y contraseña, pero podría darse el caso de que un usuario se registro normal,  en el formulario de /signin el formulario tiene onSubmit={handleSubmit} y los input solo tienen type  espero eso ayude con la explicación de como se hace el registro

Pues como que como sería? rol: string[], puedes crear un type o enum para solamente admitir usuario o terapeuta.
